# Try to move the table to the left, but failed

Tags: latex, tex

I was trying to reposition my table a bit left to the page, so I try `\hskip -2cm` or `\hspace{-2cm}` But non of these can move the table and here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}


\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}


\maketitle
\section{Introduction}



\section{Data Summary}





\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\small

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\hskip -2cm
\caption{Summary of numeric variables}

\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccccc}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{5}{c}{(1)}                                         \\
                    &\multicolumn{5}{c}{}                                            \\
                    &       count&        mean&          sd&         min&         max\\
\hline
Unemployment Rate   &         170&      8.3323&      4.1395&      3.1000&     26.0919\\
log of spending per person for secondary education&         168&      9.0229&      0.4344&      7.6109&      9.9616\\
log of spending per person for teriary education&         165&      9.5241&      0.3967&      8.7797&     10.7478\\
log of exchange rate&         170&      1.0983&      2.0997&     -0.4986&      7.0522\\
log of GDP per person&         168&     10.5306&      0.3592&      9.7330&     11.5213\\
log of GDP fixed purchasing power&         165&     27.0045&      1.4905&     23.3668&     30.5051\\
log of GDP growth   &         159&      1.2268&      0.7896&     -1.7458&      3.0063\\
Long-term interest rate on government bonds&         165&      3.8447&      2.1387&      0.5511&     10.5465\\
Short-term interest rate&         170&      1.7675&      1.9971&      0.0078&     10.3317\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item Source: OECD (2019), Education at a Glance Database, http://stats.oecd.org
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\section{Methodology}

\end{document}
```

and my table looks like this:
[image]

and I want to make my table left about a least 1.5cm.
Is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having your table project into the margin is not a good style for a layout that is not specifically designed to have additional space in the margins for this. The margin should belong to the reader to easily hold your document, adding notes etc. If there is not enough space things like Fermat's Last Theorem are your fault :)

Instead I suggest to use a `tabularx` to fit the table into the available space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}


\maketitle
\section{Introduction}



\section{Data Summary}





\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\small

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\hskip -2cm
\caption{Summary of numeric variables}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XS[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=2.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=-1.4]S[table-format=2.4]@{}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{5}{c}{(1)}                                        \\\addlinespace 
                    &       {count}&        {mean}&          {sd}&         {min}&         {max}\\
\midrule
Unemployment Rate   &         170&      8.3323&      4.1395&      3.1000&     26.0919\\
log of spending per person for secondary education&         168&      9.0229&      0.4344&      7.6109&      9.9616\\
log of spending per person for teriary education&         165&      9.5241&      0.3967&      8.7797&     10.7478\\
log of exchange rate&         170&      1.0983&      2.0997&     -0.4986&      7.0522\\
log of GDP per person&         168&     10.5306&      0.3592&      9.7330&     11.5213\\
log of GDP fixed purchasing power&         165&     27.0045&      1.4905&     23.3668&     30.5051\\
log of GDP growth   &         159&      1.2268&      0.7896&     -1.7458&      3.0063\\
Long-term interest rate on government bonds&         165&      3.8447&      2.1387&      0.5511&     10.5465\\
Short-term interest rate&         170&      1.7675&      1.9971&      0.0078&     10.3317\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item Source: OECD (2019), Education at a Glance Database, http://stats.oecd.org
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\section{Methodology}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some other comments:

- Try to avoid `[H]`, this is usually a guaranty for bad suboptimal placement of floats. I suggest `[htbp]` instead
- `*{1}{ccccc}` can be shorted to either `ccccc` or `*{5}{c}`
- You already load the `booktabs` package, so I suggest to use `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline` because they have much better spacing around them
- instead of manually adding empty lines in the table, I suggest the `\addlinespace` macro from the `booktabs` package
- With the `S` column from the `siunitx` package you can align the numbers by their decimal marker and use actual minus signs instead of cheating with hyphens
- you should check the significant figures of your values. If your standard deviation is between 0.3 and 4.1, it makes no sense to give the values with 4 decimal places.

Comment: “Having your table project into the margin is not a good style” — why? Having wide tables and figures project into the outer margin is seen at least occasionally in nicely typeset material, and can be effective. Your table looks nice as well, of course.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OK, my statement might have been a bit too generic. In cases with a relatively narrow text and a margin that already takes into account the additional space for tables/figures it will look nice (something like classic thesis class comes to mind), but not for the normal page layout of article class. Here I consider the margin to belong to the reader, for easy holding of the paper and maybe notes.

Comment: What is the different between [htbp] and [H]. I try the different placement and find out that [h] means differernt things too

Comment: @W.Yan `[htbp]` means that latex will try to insert your table **h**ere, i.e. at the position it is in your text and if there is not enough room at this position (for example because you are at the end of a page), it will move it to the **t**op of the next page, the **b**ottom of the page or a separate **p**age if there is really no better solution. **H** is a special option from the float package and is stricter than **h**. If there is not enough room to insert your table right here, it will add as much unnecessary white space as necessary to squeeze the table in there. This can be very ugly.